# How to translate "the white accessories tray"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

In the context of packaging, it's a foam insert inside a cardboard box to put some accessories (so it's the tray that's white, not the accessories :-)):

[image]

My best guess so far is "la mousse d’emballage blanche" but that doesn't feel right somehow.

This wording is part of a sentence on a label/sheet of paper that says "Please ensure that the white accessories tray has been removed from the cardboard packaging before discarding." in various languages, one of which is French.

Comment: It's not easy to provide an accurate translation when the context is missing. From the purchaser point of view, this is only packing foam, whose time of usefulness is most likely very limited. From a manufacturer's point of view, if a reference to the specific part is required, then “mousse d’emballage blanche” blankets all of the white stuff protecting any part of the product. It is clearly not specific enough for this one part only.

Comment: @Montéedelait thanks for the feedback. The extract is part of a label that instruct people not to throw it away. I'll amend the question to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal translation seems all right. As the English mentions no foam, the same can be done for the French;

- Le plateau blanc des accessoires *or*
- Le plateau blanc pour les accessoires

While adding a precision concerning the type of packaging, the following is a bit long;

- Le plateau blanc compartimenté pour les accessoires

I wonder whether it's not better to forget about the colour as well, which after all helps little in identifying the tray.

- Le plateau compartimenté pour les accessoires
- Le plateau compartimenté des accessoires

Comment: Thanks. In the end I went for "le plateau compartimenté en mousse".

Comment: That, as well, is a possibility I'd be hard put to criticise.

Answer (score 2):

Dans votre contexte vous pouvez traduire par "plateau blanc de calage des accessoires" ou "plateau blanc de protection des accessoires".

Le terme technique souvent utilisé pour ce type de produit d'emballage est "mousse de calage" ou "mousse anti-choc".